# are media queries or calculations required for image resizing to force no container margins on a grid layout?

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox, grid

Is it possible to change this Codepen:
https://codepen.io/trynn/pen/gObxmZJ

Where the images resize without media queries or using calculations and leave no container margin for any screen size?

Right now, depending on your screen size, you may or may not have a right margin.

Requirement 1: The images need to stay a max of 200px and a min of 100px.

Requirement 2: An unknown number of images, but all are squares.

Are the following examples of media queries/ calc required to accomplish this?

example 1 (have multipe media queries hard coding the breaking poitns and column counts) :

```
     @media (max-width: 1200px) {
      #squares {
       -moz-column-count:    4;
       -webkit-column-count: 4;
       column-count:         4;
       }
      }
```

example 2 (don't think this will work )?

```
        minmax(100px, 200px)
```

example 3

get actual screen size in javascript and then adjust the max-width of the image
based on a precalculation / formal?

Is there a better way to handle this task?

Answer (score 0):

set `max-width: 200px;` and `min-width: 100px;` and set `width` to any appropriate value, with the unit `vw`, which is veiwport width. If you want **n** pictures in a row than set the width to a value equal to 100/n vw.